# Dynamic Variable Scheduler Class

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, dynamic-apex

I'm looking to pass a variable to my scheulder class when scheduling a batch job. The idea is that I'm scheduling the class multiple times, but passing in a different variable each time.

Example:

```
String cron = '0 0 0,17 ? * SAT *';
System.schedule('BatchOpportunityOwnerAssignment Daily Package Lead',
    cron, new BatchOpportunityOwnerAssignmentScheduler('Package Lead'));

String cron = '0 0 0,18 ? * SAT *'; 
System.schedule('BatchOpportunityOwnerAssignment Daily Non Package Lead', 
    cron, new BatchOpportunityOwnerAssignmentScheduler('Non Package Lead'));
```

Here's what my current class looks like now:

```
global class BatchOpportunityOwnerAssignmentScheduler implements Schedulable {
        global void execute( SchedulableContext sc ) {
            BatchOpportunityOwnerAssignment apBatch = new
 BatchOpportunityOwnerAssignment(VARIABLE HERE);
            database.executebatch(apBatch,50);
    }
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Please use code blocks, not quotes, to format your code. Right now, it's not clear what you're asking; you can [edit] to clarify. It looks like you need to write a constructor for your scheduler class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just add a constructor:

```
global class BatchOpportunityOwnerAssignmentScheduler implements Schedulable {
  String variableHere;
  global BatchOpportunityOwnerAssignmentScheduler(String variableHere) {
    this.variableHere = variableHere;
  }
  global void execute(SchedulableContext context) {
    Database.executeBatch(new BatchOpportunityOwnerAssignment(variableHere), 50);
  }
}
```

Note: If you're not an ISV, it is recommended that you use `public` instead of `global`.

Comment: Don't think you need the `global` access modifier.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I made no assumption, it could easily be for an ISV that wants to do this, but definitely worth observing.

Comment: Adding the constructor worked. thanks!